# Two loops, exclude post from first loop in second loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress page which has two loops like so...

```
<?php 
global $post;
$args = array(
    'showposts'        => 1,
    'category_name'    => 'videos',
    'meta_key'         => 'feature-image',
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);  
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
$exclude_featured = $post->ID;
?>
<span class="featured">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</span>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now I need to use $exclude_featured in my second loop some how to exclude that post from that loop. I've tried a few implementations but none of them have worked. I have tried adding the following above the while statement for the second loop...

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&exclude='.$exclude_featured );
```

and this...

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'exclude' => $exclude_featured ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

.. and have had no luck. I've noticed that by using either of these two snippets they also render my pre_get_posts function which sets the number of posts to display useless.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I've tried adding the following lines before the `while` statement on the second loop..

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post__not_in' => $exclude_featured ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

However I still have not had any success, it brings up the following error:

> Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an
>   array in
>   /home/myuser/public_html/mysitedirectory/wp-includes/query.php on line
>   2162
>
> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in
>   /home/myuser/public_html/mysitedirectory/wp-includes/query.php on line
>   2162

Comment: I've also tried changing $excluded_featured = 17875; to make sure its not simply the variable thats not in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could substitute your last three lines with these:

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if ( $exclude_featured == get_the_ID() )
    continue;

the_title();
endwhile;
?>
```

[continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

This will, however, result in that you're having one less post to display. If you'd like to keep your post count exactly the same, you would need to exclude the post in the query. The query in the question is pretty close to being correct, but post__not_in has to be an array, and not an integer. All you need to do is wrap your `$exclude_featured` in an array, and your query should work.

Your query should look like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge(
    $wp_query->query_vars,
    array(
        'post__not_in' => array(
            $exclude_featured
        )
    )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Although this method does work, its not the solution I was hoping for. If this is used then rather than showing 10 posts it will show 9 posts because one of them is the $exclude_featured.
What I would like to do is have it excluded from the actual query itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have updated my answer to reflect this. (You just need to wrap the unwanted post ID in an array to make your query work).

Comment: Just before I refresh your page to see your update I figured out the exact same solution lol. But thanks your answer it spot on!